# How to make different shape nodes in automata in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, automata

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=7 cm, scale = 0.6, transform shape]

      \node[initial,state] (A)                      {$e, n, s$};
      \node[state]         (B) [right of=A]         {$w, (p+1)\%W, (p+1)\%N$};
      \node[state]         (C) [below of=A]     {$(q+1)\%W, n, x$};



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the following output:

[image]

How can I make all of them of same size? how to draw ellipse instead such that it doesn't look that big?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to define a state `elliptic`, for example by means of:

```
\tikzset{elliptic state/.style={draw,ellipse}}
```

The `ellipse` requires the library `shapes.geometric`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata,}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{elliptic state/.style={draw,ellipse}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=7 cm, scale = 0.6, transform shape]

      \node[initial,elliptic state] (A)                      {$e, n, s$};
      \node[elliptic state]         (B) [right of=A]         {$w, (p+1)\%W, (p+1)\%N$};
      \node[elliptic state]         (C) [below of=A]     {$(q+1)\%W, n, x$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

To have nodes of the same size you can specify which are the minimum width and height of the shape, but beware that ultimately this depends of the width of your text.

The example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata,}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{elliptic state/.style={draw,ellipse,minimum width=6cm,minimum height=1.5cm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=7 cm, scale = 0.6, transform shape]

  \node[initial,elliptic state] (A)                      {$e, n, s$};
  \node[elliptic state]         (B) [right of=A]         {$w, (p+1)\%W, (p+1)\%N$};
  \node[elliptic state]         (C) [below of=A]     {$(q+1)\%W, n, x$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How should I handle accepted nodes? Is there a clean way to draw an inner ellipse?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha Sure, I guess you might just want to add `double` option within `elliptic state`.