# How to center text in a ellipse and to draw circle nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, floats, tikz-styles, ellipsis

I have spend much time on this figure too and I have tried different types of tikz, pstricks and multido use packages. I would like to create a figure, which look like this:

[image]

I have wrote following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (10,0) ellipse (1.7cm and 0.9cm);
\draw (5,0) ellipse (1.7cm and 0.9cm);
\draw (2,-3) ellipse (1.7cm and 0.9cm);
\draw (2,3) ellipse (1.7cm and 0.9cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

I need to put a centered text in the ellipses and lines to each one. Can someone please tell me how to do it?

A huge thank you!

Comment: Could you please check whether [How to make different shape nodes in automata in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75403/13304) help?

Comment: You have changed this question so that the answers no longer address it. You have altered the code so that it no longer compiles. How can other people with similar questions now find the solutions provided after you changed the original question?

Comment: I fully agree with cfr; you should roll back to the original question and the same should do ignasi. Changing a question in a way that invalidates existing answers should be avoided. Ask a new one, with a link to this question, instead.

Comment: @cfr I am sorry. The text has now been updated. I can't role it back, but as I mentioned in this post, this is an updated version, which means all of the old content is still there (just without the preamble -it is there NOW).

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you @egreg- I just need some help. Can you help me?

Comment: @A.F. You can roll it back. Click on "edited ## mins ago", scroll down to the number of whatever revision the answers addressed, and click "rollback", accept the small message that comes up, then ask a follow-up question referencing this one.

Comment: Hi Alenanno. I have tried twice times now. If I roll back to 19th hours ago, it is the same text and not the hold one. Is there another way of bringing it back?

Comment: @egreg I've rolled the question back as A. F. seems to have had trouble doing so. A. F.: I just did what Alenanno described. I'm not sure why it didn't work for you - it certainly should have! Please do as egreg suggested and ask a follow-up if you need further help.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution 1 as asked in the first version of the OP**:

I leave the fine tuning to you. Just adapt the height and width of the ellipses and set `\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=xxx, row sep=xxx]...` as you please. If you want to change the arrow heads, you will do some search on this site here. Plenty of help is given all over the place.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={%
            ,ellipse
            ,minimum width=4cm
            ,minimum height=1cm
            ,draw
            ,align=center
            }}]
    Expectations 
    \arrow[<->, bend right,start anchor=190,end anchor=170]{dd}{D} 
    \arrow{dr}[swap]{A}
    \arrow{drr}{F}
    &[-2cm] & \\
    & Disconfirmation \arrow{r}{C} & Satisfaction\\
    Performance
    \arrow{ur}{B}
    \arrow{urr}[swap]{E}
    & &
\end{tikzcd}        
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Solution 2 as asked in version 3 of the OP**:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={%
                ,ellipse
                ,minimum width=4.5cm
                ,minimum height=1.5cm
                ,draw
                ,align=center
            }}
            ,every arrow/.append style={-LaTeX, >=LaTeX}
            ,row sep=2cm
            ,column sep=2cm
            ]
            Expectations 
            \arrow[<->, bend right=50,start anchor=185,end anchor=175]{dd}{D(+)} 
            \arrow{dr}[swap]{A(-)}
            \arrow{drr}{F(\pm)}
            &[-4cm] & \\
            & (Dis)confirmation \arrow{r}{C(+)} & Satisfaction\\
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}General\\ Performance\end{tabular}
            \arrow{ur}{B(+)}
            \arrow{urr}[swap]{E(+)}
            & &
        \end{tikzcd}        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear LaRiFaRi, Thank you so much. Is there a way, how I can change the link D, so the link looks like as the picture?

Comment: @A.F. Do you mean the arrow? Do what ever you like with it: `\arrow[<->, >=LaTeX, bend right=50,start anchor=185,end anchor=175]{dd}{\mathsf D} `

Comment: Yes, nice. Two things, how do I change the arrow type, so it looks like the one in the picture and how do i resize the font size? And how do I spread the two ellipses (Performance) and (Expecactions) more, as shown? Sorry about all these questions

Comment: @A.F. Your last question is answered by my second sentence. The rest: read the first sentence. This is not a "do it for me" page and I do not have more time to spend on this. Please show some effort by your own and ask specific questions. Changing the font-size in Ti*k*Z drawings can be found around here, changing arrow heads of `tikz-cd` can be found around here, ...

Comment: If I put an extra word in after Disconfirmation, i.e. "Disconfirmation Confirmation". How do I make a linebreak? I have tried to look around, the same with the other questions.

Answer (score 3):

Proposed solution for original question:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ball/.style={ellipse, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, draw}, >=LaTeX]
\node[ball] (dis) {Disconfirmation};
\node[ball, below left=2cm and 5mm of dis] (per) {Performance};
\node[ball, above left=2cm and 5mm of dis] (exp) {Expectations};
\node[ball, right=2cm of dis] (sat) {Satisfaction};

\draw[->] (exp) -- node [below] {A} (dis);
\draw[->] (exp) -- node [above] {F} (sat);
\draw[->] (per) -- node [above] {B} (dis);
\draw[->] (per) -- node [below] {E} (sat);
\draw[->] (dis) -- node [above] {C} (sat);
\draw[<->] (per) to [in=200,out=160] node [right] {A} (exp);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

`nodes` can be ellipses loading shapes.geometric library. If `minimum width` and `minimum height` are large enough to fit the largest content, all nodes will have similar size. If `align` option is defined, `\\` can be used inside node's contents to break lines. Another option could be to define certain `text width` which will automatically break lines, although it can be still forced with `\\`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ball/.style={ellipse, minimum width=4.5cm, 
       minimum height=1cm, align=center, draw}, >=LaTeX]
\node[ball] (dis) {Disconfirmation(Dis)confirmation};
\node[ball, below left=2cm and 5mm of dis] (per) {General Performance};
\node[ball, above left=2cm and 5mm of dis] (exp) {Expectations};
\node[ball, right=2cm of dis] (sat) {Satisfaction};

\draw[->] (exp) -- node [below][below left] {A $(-)$} (dis);
\draw[->] (exp) -- node [above][above right] {F $(\pm)$} (sat);
\draw[->] (per) -- node [above][above left] {B $(+)$} (dis);
\draw[->] (per) -- node [below][below right] {E $(+)$} (sat);
\draw[->] (dis) -- node [above] {C $(+)$} (sat);
\draw[<->] (per) to [in=200,out=160] node [right] {AD $(+)$} (exp);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ignasi, can you maybe help me with my updated questions?

Comment: @A.F. you can start with http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240941/1952

Comment: @A.F. answer updated.

Comment: @Ignasi I asked the OP to roll back to the previous version of the question.